# How to add light effects to buildings in unity (building light)

Tags: unity-game-engine, light

To be more precise I need a type of lighting that looks good to put on building models that already have a texture, I can't texturize the textures with light turned on apartments such as in GTA5 because I do not know how to create textures. I tried putting point light and spot light on buildings but it looks pretty bad, neon cubes are not good either as it makes the building look back.
I hope you understand what I meant.

[image: HD wallpaper: night, city lights, Grand Theft Auto V, GTA5, video games]

Like that but no texturization

Comment: Are you using HDRP, URP or Built In Render Pipeline....

Comment: This doesn't feel like a programming question

Comment: I didn't know if it needed programming so I included c just in case, I'm using build in render pipeline

Comment: I suggest you use HDRP, to get realistic lighting. HDRP is made for this purpose.

Comment: Okay if I use it, I have to add something like lighting no? So what do I add

Comment: Check the edited link in Question thanks @Obscure021

Comment: According to the image, the title of this question should be **How to add building lights**.

Comment: Okay I edited the question, but I still dont have a solution, do you know any?

Comment: If you want to achieve the results in the image, Render Pipeline doesn't matter much. It can be done in the Built-In Render Pipeline. @DamirShabayev

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the results in the image, you should use an emission map.

Creating these types of lights using the `Light` Component is inefficient. You *must not* Spot Light **OR** Point Light for this purpose.

---

**SOME YOUTUBE VIDEOS:**

- [How to TURN ON Lights in Unity](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bU1sBNfbdM4)
- [How to Use EMISSIVE MATERIALS in Unity! Step-by-Step Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2PBgCl-zIZQ)